# When converting dates to other timezone do you need to store the time?

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

When using PHP's [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) to convert a stored date to a different timezone later, do you need to store the time information (e.g., 2012-12-31 00:00:00 instead of just 2012-12-31)? It appears that if I just store the date, the timezone conversion is inaccurate so I'm not sure if time information is really needed or I'm just missing something?

Comment: Why would you not store the time, if you plan on effective the time based on timezones later? Seems like adjusting the timezone on a date would be a waste to me.

Comment: Its better to store the timestamp in stead of the date

Comment: According to the examples in the manual, `2012-12-31` is the same as `2012-12-31 00:00:00`, and if you construct this object with no timezone, then PHP will use you computer timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timezone conversions work by hour offsets - with out the time stored (atleast hours), you can't accurately calculate the difference.

An example to consider - say you want to group data by day, the dates are stored in `UTC` but your client is in `PST`.

A row was created on `2012-12-31 08:00:00` in `UTC`, but you stored `2012-12-31`.

```
$date = new DateTime('2012-12-31', new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
echo $date->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles') )->format('Y-m-d');
//2012-12-30

$datetime = new DateTime('2012-12-31 08:00:00', new DateTimeZone('UTC') );
echo $datetime->setTimezone( new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles') )->format('Y-m-d');
//2012-12-31
```

The date should reflect `2012-12-31` in PST, but with out the hour offset it would be converted incorrectly.

Also, as Samuel Cook answered, unless you explicitly store the `datetime` in your database under a single timezone, you should store the timezone as well, so you know what your converting from.

Answer (score 1):

As well as saving the time you should also save the current timezone of that date that you are savings. This will effectively ensure that when you change to other timezones you know what to base the time off of.

Ex: `2012-11-21T15:52:01+0000`

[More information here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)